# erro_persistence_mysql8.0_hibernate_eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Pessoal estou na primeira aula de persistence, mas o codigo nao esta dando certo,

**arquivo persistence mysql:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">`

    <persistence-unit name="exemploPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cadastro_cliente"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

            <!-- validate | update | create | create-drop -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conversando com um professor DBA identifiquei que a versao do Hibernate estava incompativel com o Banco mysql, e ele ajustou o codigo por conta do timezone:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
</code><code>   
<persistence-unit name="exemploPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cadastro_cliente?serverTimezone=UTC" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />

            <!-- validate | update | create | create-drop -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: @ngueno vlw pela ajuda na formatação, não estava conseguindo ajustar, mas como precisava de ajuda no codigo eu postei daquela forma. nas proximas vou melhorando a formatação do mesmo.

Comment: Não esquenta não, demora acostumar :) uma coisa que você sempre deve fazer é substituir tabs por espaços, os tabs atrapalham toda a formatação

Comment: entendi, esse motivo que fez com que a formatação ficasse desalinhada ? o uso do TAB ?, pois nao consegui colocar todo codigo dentro do bloco.

Comment: sim, ela quebra todas as tags, outra coisa é colar o texto  todo normalmente, selecionar a parte de código e então marcar ele como código utilizando o botão do editor

Comment: Blza, muito obrigado!!!

Comment: De nada, seja bem vindo :)

Comment: @henrique.marques Seguem umas dicas de formatação: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @hkotsubo, vlw.... acho que foi nesse link que eu vi mesmo, muito obrigado pela atenção.